# Ошибка генерации bitcode в Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

Проект содержит в себе библиотеку `NMSSH` для работы с SFTP-серверами. При обычной сборке компиляция и работа линкера проходит успешно, т.к в этом случае не генерируется bitcode. При архивации проекта для публикации на *AppStore*, bitcode генерируется, и линкер выводит ошибку:

[image: clang: error]

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '.../NMSSH.framework/NMSSH' was built without full bitcode. All
>   frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive
>   or Install build file '.../NMSSH.framework/NMSSH' for architecture
>   arm64

Библиотека компилируется локально из исходников. В опциях компилятора поставил `-fembed-bitcode`, build target поставил на Generic iOS Device, после этого подшиваю перекомпилированный фреймворк в проект, архивирую, и снова та же ошибка.

Bitcode в проекте отключать не хочется, хотя это решит проблему. Хотелось бы собрать проект полностью с включенным bitcode.

В проекте библиотеки NMSSH я вижу две схемы сборки: `NMSSH.framework` и `NMSSH Static.framework`. В проект подшивается первая, нестатичная. Может, проблема в этом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что кастомный флаг `-embed-bitcode` ставился компилятором после флага `-embed-bitcode-marker`, который ставится по умолчанию, и следовательно, игнорировался. Правильным решением было собирать библиотеку не с помощью опции "Build", а с помощью "Archive". XCode при этом прячет собранный фреймворк в совсем не очевидную папку, но она легко ищется в конфигурации компилятора. При архивации по умолчанию используется флаг `-fembed-bitcode`, и после этого проект собирается без проблем. Надеюсь, я кому-то помог!